# sql count frequency of rows that start by

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by

Let's take the following `dataframe`:

```
     Name
    ==================
    'Samsung Galaxy 3'
    'Samsung Galaxy 4'
    'Samsung Galaxy 4'
    'Samsung Galaxy 7'
    'ZTE'
    'ZTE'
    'Motorola'
    'Motorola'
    'Iphone'
    'Iphone'
    'Iphone'
```

For some reason I want to count by grouping by only the Iphone and the phone which start with Samsung (whatever the model).

I tried to do :

```
SELECT Name, count(Name)
FROM dataframe 
WHERE dataframe LIKE '%Samsung' OR dataframe LIKE '%Iphone'
GROUP BY Name
```

Obviously I get

```
  Name                count(Name)
 ==================|================
'Samsung Galaxy 3' |  1
'Samsung Galaxy 4' |  2
'Samsung Galaxy 7' |  1
'Iphone'           |  3
```

But what I am trying to get is to group all Samsung. The output should look like

```
  Name                count(Name)
     ==================|================
    'Samsung Galaxy'   |  4
    'Iphone'           |  3
```

Is it possible to solve that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'Samsung%' then 'Samsung'
             WHEN Name LIKE 'Iphone%' then 'Iphone'
             ELSE 'other'
        END) as which, COUNT(*)
FROM dataframe 
WHERE name LIKE 'Samsung%' OR name LIKE 'Iphone%'
GROUP BY which;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I could not solve it because I did not know the CASE function. Thanks to you I have learnt this usefull function. Best regards,

Comment: @S12000 . . . Technically, `case` is an *expression* not a *function*.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps a little more flexible assuming you are wanting to get rid of the generation number but keep the manufacturer and phone type you could alter the string using index of last space (' ') and group by the result.

```
SELECT
  left(name,length(name) - strpos(reverse(name),' ')) as which
  ,COUNT(*)
FROM dataframe
GROUP BY
  left(name,length(name) - strpos(reverse(name),' '))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a915e/10/0): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a915e/10/0

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer